# Jenkins Maven release fails due to log files from unit tests

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, logging, jenkins

I unfortunately may have two questions in one, or rather the solution may go two different ways. I have log4j loggers set up in a few classes that I unit test on. When I run `mvn clean install` it obviously runs those tests and in turn creates a log file (that is usually empty as nothing exciting is being logged). This isn't necessarily a problem except that Jenkins doesn't seem to like this when I do `Perform Maven Release`. It yells about the workspace having local changes and it cites the log file before declaring failure.

I know its the unit tests because if I changed them to integration tests or ignore them, everything works fine. But I'd like a solution not a workaround.

Are there configurations in Jenkins that can allow me to remedy this?

Or is there a strategy for mocking or ignoring logging for Unit tests?

I don't necessarily want to ignore them, but it is interfering with creating a release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite aware of what `Perform Maven Release` does, but I can suggest a couple of solutions:

1. Remove the log file from your source code repository (as the log files gets regenerated on every run, I don't think it should reside in your source code repository).
2. Add the path of the offending log file to a list of files that are ignored by version control (e.g. git uses a file called gitignore - https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Amit has the solution listed as #2 which works for us - In our shop we use SVN, so we add these files to our .svn-ignore, and the `mvn release:prepare` will work successfully.

Comment: Brilliant. Will find out if this works for good on the next release, but I'm not seeing it in the workspace on the job list. Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Amit has some good ideas, and I'll suggest a few more:

- Use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) for logging in your project, and don't bind a logging implementation during the test phase
- going one better, bind [slf4j-test](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/slf4j-test/) during the test phase, which logs to memory. Then you can also write tests against your logging to ensure it happens when you expect it to.